# Capture the event of smart table personalisation ok button

Tags: sapui5

In my smart table when I open the personalisation dialog box, I want to capture the event of OK button of that dialog box.

I found an online code but it didn't work for me as `oSmartTable._oPersController` doesn't exists.

```
var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("MeldungenSmartTable"); //Get Hold of Smart Table

var oPersController = oSmartTable._oPersController;
var oPersDialog = oPersController._oDialog;
if (oPersDialog) {
    oPersDialog.addEventDelegate({
        onAfterRendering: function() {
            //OK button event
            oPersDialog.attachOk(function(oEvent) {
                alert("In Personalization Dialog");
            });
        }
    }, oPersDialog);
}
```

Comment: You can check the docu https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable and there is no such event on a SmartTable. Furthermore, you should not access any private properties which are not documented in the API because they are subject to change and not part of any contract. The underscore illustrates this also visually in the debugger / code.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you run this function after the smartTable has completely rendered. I recommend putting it within `OnAfterRendering`.

I've just tested and it is working.